# Remove packages Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: package-management, uninstall

I'm doing a bit of cleaning on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
I've noted that when I install a package (via apt-get install packageName), the depends and recommends packages linked at this package are also installed.
I'm wondering if it's possible remove the recommends packages without any problem/ lose stability?
Instead, as for the depends packages, I think that's no possible. Right?

Thanks.
Stefano

Answer (score 0):

It would quickly become a mess if that was not possible.

If you remove a package and other packages depend on it the system will remove those *if you agree to it*. Deleting a library that is in use by Unity will remove Unity BUT as long as you do not remove apt-get itself you can always re-install it with `apt-get`.

There is an extra package called `deporphan` that scans the system for libs that are no longer in use by any packages and that will remove those when you agree to it. I used it on several Ubuntu releases and it works like a charm.

[Ubuntu tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/) might be useful to you. It is sort of a command center around applications.